# In one formula of orbital velocity for circular orbit it has inverse relation with radius while in critical velocity relation it has direct. Why?

Tags: classical-mechanics, newtonian-gravity

In one formula of orbital velocity for circular orbit it has inverse relation with radius
$$v=\sqrt{\frac{GM}{r}}$$
while in critical velocity relation it has direct
$$v=\sqrt{gr}$$
Why?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Physics SE. Please edit your question include the equations you're asking about. I assume one is $v=r\omega$, which you can insert by pasting `v=r\omega` between two dollar signs.

Comment: 1.$g=GM_E\over r_E^2$ escape velocity is the relation between kinttic energy and Potential difference  rotation velocity is centripetalforce = gravitational force, so two different things.

Answer (score 0):

The two equations are the same, since
$$g=\frac{GM}{r^2}$$